# How Access to couchdb users db without admin credential

Tags: cordova, kendo-ui, couchdb

I'm writing a mobile app using phonegap, kendoUI mobile and couchdb. I've setting an admin user for my server couchdb.

A doc in /_usersdb has that format:

```
{
  _id: org.couchdb.user:foo
  name: foo
  passw: securepassword
  role: []
  type: user
  salt: complexstring
  nickName: fooNick
  mail: fooNick@mail.com
}
```

I want obtain the nickName and mail of all user, and I want that all users in /_users db can do that.

I'm sure that with admin credentials is easy. I must simply run this command:

```
curl -X GET 'http://adminUserName:adminPassword@192.168.0.111:5984/_users/_all_docs'
```

But how I can do that without admin credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_users` database is protected for looking by anyone except server or admins of `_users` database itself. Any other users may retrieve only document that is associated (and represents) with user's login name.

While behaviour isn't configurable, but you may found [public_fields](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/auth.html#couch_httpd_auth/public_fields) feature useful for your task. Once it becomes activation regular users may request `/_users/_all_docs` resource and docs of other users with limitations on returned fields: only public ones will be available. Be sure that your users are agreed that some of their information including login name will be available for the other world.

Read more about authentication database restriction in [CouchDB docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/intro/security.html#authentication-database).